# Are UIView constraints implicitly reactivated?

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have a view that hides / reveals a **Camera** button or **Send** button based on input. Initially it looks like this:

[image]

If the user starts typing, it fades out the **Camera** by setting alpha to 0, disables the constraint between the **Camera** and **textBox**, enables a constraint between the **textBox** and **Send** button, fading in the following:

[image]

To make this work, I design all the constraints in the Storyboard and selectively activate them.  This *almost* works but has some problems.

1. All the constraints are present in the Storyboard, which generates a build warning.  Is there a way to get rid of this warning?  IE, to specify but disable some constraints?
2. Even though I disable the constraints for the **Send** button in **viewDidLoad**, as soon as I call **self.view.layoutIfNeeded()** in that method, they all my constraints are re-enabled, causing an overconstrained error message on the console.
3. When I type, the **Camera** and **Send** button do properly fade in and out and the constraints cause the **textBox** to animate from left to right and back again.  However, when I rotate the device, all of the constraints are spontaneously re-enabled, even though I override **willTransitionToTraitCollection** and verify that they are correct when this method exits.  How do I prevent this?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No answer yet, but I needed a workaround and found one that works well.

Rather than activate/deactivate constraints, I found I can autolayout all elements at once like this:

[image]

And animate the **Camera** button right-constraint and alpha, and **Send** button left-constraint and alpha.  I order the elements so that the textfield is drawn last, and can overlay either with the appropriate constraint setting, in order to hide it:

[image]

In **viewDidLoad**, I capture the Interface Builder right-contraint of the **Camera**, and the left-constraint of the **Send** button.  To make the **Send** button disappear, I animate its alpha from 1 to 0 and and its left-constraint to **-sendButton.frame.width**. To animate the **Send** button to appear and the **Camera** button to disappear, I do the opposite -- animate the **Send** alpha from 0 to 1 and restore its original left-constraint while animating the **Camera**'s right-constraint to **-cameraButton.frame.width** and its respective alpha from 1 to 0.

This seems to work well.  That said, I would still like to know if there is a way of solving this by activating and deactivating constraints.

Comment: This great tip completely answered my question:
[Quick tip: More Constraint Animation Advice (Route 85)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WVlNl4JDzL4&index=2&list=PLOU2XLYxmsIKGQekfmV0Qk52qLG5LU2jO)